# Some customers get a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when upgrading my Android app. How do I fix this?

Tags: java, android, installation, java-native-interface

Several random customers get this exception every time I update my Android app. I've narrowed it down to two reasons, both related to using the jni.

1. The *.so library is deleted when the app is upgraded.
2. The *.so library is not upgraded when the app is upgraded, and the old version still remains.

The device reports do not signal that this issue is related to the OS version, memory, or anything rational. Rather than focus on why Android is having trouble upgrading the libraries, I'm hoping someone out there knows how to manually pull the libraries out of the app's APK and put them in the right directory when this error is encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you probably have an ABI mismatch - or possibly a *false* ABI mismatch caused by an Android bug that people have been talking about, where a generic arm library may not be accepted when one of the specialized varieties is preferred.

As for your workaround... you cannot write to the lib/ directory of your app's installation, though you can put a library elsewhere if you use System.load() with a precise path/filename instead of loadLibrary() with just a library name.  I don't think there's any official (as in future-proof) way to extract arbitrary contents from your apk, though it's fairly easy to do at present with the zipfile classes (with something perhaps such as Context.getPackageCodePath() to discover the location and **installation-variable** name of the apk)

Checking for the success of the library loading attempt and reporting information about the device if it fails might be as useful.

Comment: The following appears to be the issue Chris is referring to.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25321

Comment: After some research, I can confirm that this only happens on ARMv7 devices (no Intel data yet), even though my app supports generic ARM. This is happening on Android 2.3, 3.0 and 4.0.1,2,3,4. It should be fixed in Android 4.0.4r1.1. The solution is simple, just tell customers to upgrade to 4.0.4r1.1 or later.

The following appears to be the issue Chris is referring to.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25321

Just kidding. The solution is to detect this failure and notify the customer they have to uninstall, reinstall and hope for the best.